# How to use Decodable on the results of a Firestore Query on each document

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code, and I need to use Query so that I can programmatically build the query up before making the call to Firestore, but the document I get back apparently doesn't support Decodable. If I don't use Query, I cannot build up the where clauses programmatically however the documents I get back do support Decodable.  How can I get the first case to allow Decodable to work?

```
    public static func query<T: Codable>(queryFields: [String: Any]) async -> [T] {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        var ref: Query = db.collection("myDocuments")
        for (key, value) in queryFields {
            ref = ref.whereField(key, isEqualTo: value)
        }
        let snapshot = try? await ref.getDocuments()
        if let snapshot = snapshot {
            let results = snapshot.documents.compactMap { document in
                try? document.data(as: T.self) // this does not compile
            }
            return results
        } else {
            return [T]()
        }
     }
```

Comment: The problem you are facing is that if you have multiple objects that conform to `Codable`, how would Firestore's `data(as:)` method ever know which one of them to map the documents to?

Comment: the compactMap is dealing with a single document at a time and the as argument should tell it which struct to create.  This also works just fine if my var ref is not typed as Query but then I have to remove the for (key,value) loop and code the queries directly.

Comment: Something doesn't add up for me. The query has no bearing on the mapping of the document. Whether you get the document through a dynamic query, a static query, or no query, the `data(as:)` method doesn't care or could ever know how that document was acquired. Just as an aside, if you don't explicitly typecast the `ref` variable to `Query`, what you have is a collection reference. To get around that, you can just declare the variable with the first where clause in it or something that all queries have if they share a common filter, like order-by.

Comment: But what you're saying is that you have multiple objects that conform to `Codable` and that if you remove the query variable, Firestore will know which one of those objects to grab and map the document to? But if you get these documents through this dynamic query, keeping everything else the same, then Firestore will now not know which object to map the documents to?

Comment: The Query is initialized with the specific collection so only documents from that collection will be returned if any. I'll repost this with an easier example.

Comment: I have seen you have posted similar questions recently. I think you should try filling an issue in the Firebase iOS SDK [repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk), since, as far as I have seen from your current questions, it seems to be more appropriate for help there.